# Chrome Extension - Blob from Background to Context script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension attempting to record the active tab and save the blob to local storage.

The `chrome.tabCapture` is called based on a command issued by the user, after 5 seconds, the recording is stopped and make a new blob from the recorded chunks, proceed to download the file.

When the file is downloaded the file is 0 Bytes, when putting a breakpoint before, inspecting the blob it is greater than 0 Bytes. Eventually attempting to return the blob to the context script in the `sendResponse` callback.

Curious if anything is sticking out as to why the blob is empty when downloading or retruning to the context script.

Following the documentation at: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture(captureOptions, function (stream) {
    if (!stream)
        return;
    var recordedChunks = [];
    var options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9',
    };

    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
            recordedChunks.push(event.data);
        }
    }
    mediaRecorder.start();
    setTimeout(function(){
        stopRecording(stream, mediaRecorder, recordedChunks);
    }, 5000);
})


 var stopRecording = function (stream, mediaRecorder, recordedChunks) {
   mediaRecorder.stop();
   var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
       type: 'video/webm'
   });
   var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.style = 'display: none';
   a.href = url;
   a.download = 'test.webm';
   a.click();
   URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
   stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by downloading the file within the `ondataavailable` callback:

**background.js:**

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture(captureOptions, function (stream) {
    if (!stream)
        return;
    var recordedChunks = [];
    var options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9',
    };

    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.style = 'display: none';
          a.href = url;
          a.download = 'test.webm';
          a.click();
          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    }
    mediaRecorder.start();
    setTimeout(function(){
        stopRecording(stream, mediaRecorder, recordedChunks);
    }, 5000);
})


 var stopRecording = function (stream, mediaRecorder, recordedChunks) {
   mediaRecorder.stop();
   stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
 };
```